# How to distinguish between different objects using an interface

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, types, interface

I'm creating a platform system using a raycast controller that uses an interface to perform different tasks based on the type of platform with which my player is currently colliding. Some of the platform types include ice, passable blocks and muddy ground.

I want to know how to better optimize my code, as I currently call Unity's somewhat expensive "GetComponent()" function every frame, even if I never change between blocks. What I'd like to do is only call GetComponent() when I change from one type of platform to a different type of platform (i.e. muddy ground --> ice), but don't know how to do this using an interface.

I thought I would be able to compare types using enums, but you're not allowed to declare types in an interface.

```
        if (hit)
        {
            //I'd only like to run this block of code if the type of platform changes
            var platform = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<IPlatform>();

            State.IsCollidingWithPassablePlatform = platform.IsPassable;
            State.IsJumpBoosted = platform.IsJumpForce;
            State.IsBoosted = platform.IsForce;

            xForce = platform.XForce;
            yForce = platform.YForce;
            zForce = platform.ZForce;

            defaultParameters.accelerationTimeGrounded = platform.AccelerationTimeGrounded;
            defaultParameters.accelerationTimeAirborne = platform.AccelerationTimeAirborne;
```

Interface example:

```
interface IPlatform {

float AccelerationTimeGrounded { get; }
float AccelerationTimeAirborne { get; }

float XForce { get; }
float YForce { get; }
float ZForce { get; }

bool IsPassable { get; }

bool IsForce { get; }
bool IsJumpForce { get; }
```

Ice platform:

```
public class PlatformIce : MonoBehaviour, IPlatform {

public float AccelerationTimeGrounded { get { return accelerationTimeGrounded; } }
public float AccelerationTimeAirborne { get { return accelerationTimeAirborne; } }

public float XForce { get { return xForce; } }
public float YForce { get { return yForce; } }
public float ZForce { get { return zForce; } }

public virtual bool IsPassable { get { return false; } }

public bool IsForce { get { return false; } }
public bool IsJumpForce { get { return false; } }

[SerializeField]
private float accelerationTimeGrounded = 1.0f;
[SerializeField]
private float accelerationTimeAirborne = 3.0f;

private float xForce = 0;
private float yForce = 0;
private float zForce = 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you should create a class implement `MonoBehaviour` class.
Becasue the method  `GetComponent<T>()` will componet on gameObject ,which  implement `Component` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember your last GameObject and check if this one has changed

```
private lastGameObj;
[...]
if(lastGameObj!= hit.collider.gameObject) {
var platform = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<IPlatform>();
// [...] your magic here
lastGameObj= hit.collider.gameObject;
}
```

You will get an additional condition, but you won't run your code 60 times/sec inclusive that GetComponent();.

Answer (score 1):

You CAN use `enum`s inside an Interface, you just have to declare the `enum` type outside the Interface.

I.E.:

```
public enum PlatformType {Normal, Ice, Fire, etc}; //Use public only if needed, of course

interface IPlatform {
    PlatformType platformType { get; }
    //Your other stuff here
}
```

This will break encapsulation, clearly, but if you really want to use an `enum` in an interface, there's no way around it.